# jQuery not responding while trying to validate an input field

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run a jQuery file on the page but it's not responding. I'm attempting to validate the `email` input field.

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").validate({
        rules: {
            "email": {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "email": {
                required: "Enter enter valid email address",
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="test" method="post">
    email:<input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Please take time to properly format your code as code. Remove all those extra lines etc.  You might try the Edit and put the code in using the snippet button (CTRL-M)

Comment: The code for jqueryvalidation is ok. You should post your html too. What is the output of the console? Shows any errors?

Comment: no..it just remains the same..

Comment: <html>
<head><title></title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='test.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="test" method="post">
email:<input type="email" name="email" id="email">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: You should edit your question and format your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `$.validate()` function in core jQuery. You will need to add the [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to your page.

Comment: how do i add a jquery validation plugin